# functions having IVP and monotonic ONLY at rationals

Tags: real-analysis

```
  I came over this problem:
```

Given f a function who satisfies the Darboux property and who is also monotonic at the irrationals, prove that f is continuous.
I solved this assuming that f is not monotonic. Then we get that in some interval, the rationals should take an uncountable number of values (by IVT) , contradiction.This was easy.
 But I ask now: Is there a function f who satisfies the Darboux property and which is only monotonic on a countable dense subset of R? 
I tried to start from ''strange'' continuous functions ( like Cantor function) and modify them such as to preserve monotonicity and Darboux, but get rid of continuity(at least at a finite number of points), but I got stuck.
have no idea on how to approach this.

Comment: Could you explain in detail what is meant by "monotonic only at the rationals"? I have some ideas but I'm not sure if they're applicable because the def'n seems unclear to me.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers. By monotonic at the rationals I mean that given p,q rationals, $p<q$ implies $f(p)<f(q)$

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant that for every rational $q$, for $x$ in a neighborhood of $q$, $f(x)-f(q)(x-q) \ge 0$. My first comment was with this understanding of the problem.

Comment: But then what does **only** mean in your post ? It can never be the only set on which the restriction of $f$ is monotone... So what did you mean by only ? I think you should be more precise on the hypothesis in your post

Comment: Hi charMD,  define f to be monotonic on a set A iff for all p,q in A,  p<q implies f(p)<f(q). My question, rephrased, is : Can A be countable and dense if f has Darboux property?